# Simple javascript form validation not working in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, validation

I have a simple form to take user input. User must fill very fields in that form. If they don't, javascript gives the alert message but it's not working. I am not getting alert message if I submit the form empty. Here's my form.html:

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate(){
    if(document.simple_form.session.value == "" ||
    document.simple_form.hostname.value == "" ||
    document.simple_form.username.value == ""
    document.simple_form.password.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please fill out all fields before clicking Load!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</head>


<body>

    <form action="." method="post" onsubmit="return Validate();" name="simple_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Session</legend>
                <label for="input-one" class="float"><strong>Session Name:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="session" id="sess" type="text" size="30" /><br />

                <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>RemoteHost:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="hostname"  id="host" type="text" size="30" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value='ngs.pradhi.com:/upload' }" onfocus="if(this.value=='ngs.pradhi.com:/upload') { this.value='' }" value="ngs.pradhi.com:/upload" />

                <label for="input-three" class="float"><strong>Username:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="username"  id="user" type="text" size="30" />

                <label for="input-four" class="float"><strong>Password:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="password"  id="pass" type="password" size="30" />
        </fieldset>



    <p><input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Load" /></p>
        <p><input class="save-button" type="reset"  name="cancel" value="Cancel" /></p>
    </form>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, it might be easier to use `document.getElementById` than the `document.form.element` notation you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a final `||` in your `Validate()` function.

I've got a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aidanewen/dPx9d/) (I added a couple of `</br>`'s too).